# How can we resolve this issue ? Deprecated Functionality: str_replace():

Tags: magento2.4.5, data-migration-tool

I'm trying to fix the error with this `(return sprintf($path,str_replace('contents_', '', $content));)` code but it's not working. anyone have idea how we can resolve it?
Console error...

> [2023-02-07T17:48:14.257774+00:00][INFO][mode: data][stage: data
> migration][step: Map Step]: started
> [2023-02-07T17:48:14.258237+00:00][INFO][mode: data][stage: data
> migration][step: Map Step]: started 27% [=======>--------------------]
> Remaining Time: 1 hr In ErrorHandler.php line 62:
> Deprecated Functionality: str_replace(): Passing null to parameter #3
> ($subject) of type array|string is deprecated in
> E:\xampp81\htdocs\m3\vendor\magento\data-migration-tool\src\Migration\Handler\Placeholder.php
> on line 65

Answer (score 0):

PHP8.1
(return sprintf($path,str_replace('contents_', '', $content));)

That error indicates somewhere in your code passing null to the third parameter when calling a PHP function that is deprecated in PHP 8.1.

update your code by:-

```
  (return sprintf($path,str_replace('contents_', '_', $content));)
```

or

```
(return sprintf($path,str_replace('contents_', '-', $content));
```